# Checking if all letters in a string (from any major spoken language) are upper-casee

Tags: string, internationalization, tcl

I simply want to check if all the letters that occur in a string are upper-case (if they have lower- and upper-case variants). Tcl's built-in procs don't behave quite as desired, e.g.,

```
string is upper "123A"
```

returns false, but I would want it to return true. I would also want it to return true if the A were replaced with, say, an upper-case Cyrillic letter, or a letter from another popular alphabet that doesn't have a case. I could simply filter out all non-letters from the string, but that's not so simple I think when you're trying to handle letters from languages other than just English.

Comment: `stringToCheck.ToUpper() == stringToCheck`

Comment: I was under the impression that the equivalent in Tcl (string toupper) failed for foreign alphabets, but it looks like this may have been fixed in recent versions of Tcl.

Comment: @ZachConn I don't know about Tcl. But Php for example has a function strtoupper() that suffers the same problem. But the php function **mb_** strtoupper() doesn't.

Comment: @nl-x: All strings in Tcl are transparently mb-aware. (There have been some historic bugs, but they're just that: historic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you don't want `string is upper` as that checks if the string is *just* upper case letters. (Numbers aren't letters.)

Instead, you want to do:

```
set str "123A"
if {$str eq [string toupper $str]} {
    # It's upper-case by your definition...
}
```